Some uploaded images in WordPress get "Generated Image" title and slug, while most retain original names
I'm running WordPress 6.7.1 on AWS Lightsail.
I have a batch of 51 images that were all processed identically in Lightroom from raw files. When uploading these images, 7 of them inexplicably get renamed with the title "Generated Image" and slugs like "generated-image-6", while the remaining 44 images maintain their original names.
Troubleshooting steps attempted:

Simplified file names (e.g., "test image.jpg") to rule out
character/length issues
Flipped images horizontally
Disabled all plugins
Changed WordPress theme
Consulted AI assistants (ChatGPT, Claude, and Grok)
Re-installed wordpress

The issue persists despite all these attempts. Looking for insights into what might cause this inconsistent behavior and how to resolve it.



The issue is likely due to the "Object Name" metadata field being set to "Generated image" in some of your files. You can check this using:
exiftool -ObjectName yourfile.jpg

To fix affected images, clear this metadata field:
exiftool -ObjectName= yourfile.jpg

After clearing the metadata, the images should upload with their original filenames. You can process multiple files at once using:
exiftool -ObjectName= *.jpg

This is a known WordPress behavior where it uses the Object Name metadata field (if present) to generate the title and slug, overriding the filename.
